# Grunt returns errors for all tasks

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Grunt return errors "No * targets found." or "Task * not found." for all tasks.
Also grunt --help doesn't show some tasks as available, for example "build" and "test" tasks.

This config seems to be working before. But it didn't change(git ensures this).

What's wrong with it?

Here is my Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
  grunt.initConfig({
    yeoman: {
      app: 'app',
      dist: 'dist'
    },
    phonegap: {
      config: {
        root: 'dist',
        config: 'config.xml',
        cordova: '.cordova',
        path: 'phonegap',
        plugins: [],
        platforms: ['ios', 'android', 'wp8'],
        verbose: false
      }
    },
    compass: {
      server: {
        options: {
          sassDir: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/',
          cssDir: '.tmp/styles/'
        }
      },
    },
    watch: {
      compass: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.{scss,sass}'],
        tasks: ['compass:server', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      styles: {
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        tasks: ['copy:styles', 'autoprefixer']
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          livereload: '<%= connect.options.livereload %>'
        },
        files: ['<%= yeoman.app %>/*.html', '.tmp/styles/{,*/}*.css', '{.tmp,<%= yeoman.app %>}/scripts/{,*/}*.js', '<%= yeoman.app %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp,svg}']
      }
    },
    connect: {
      options: {
        port: 9000,
        livereload: 35729,
         hostname: 'localhost'
      },
      livereload: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: ['.tmp', '<%= yeoman.app %>']
        }
      },
      test: {
        options: {
          base: ['.tmp', 'test', '<%= yeoman.app %>']
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          open: true,
          base: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }
      }
    },
    clean: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          dot: true,
          src: ['.tmp', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/*', '!<%= yeoman.dist %>/.git*']
        }]
      },
      server: '.tmp'
    },
    jshint: {
      options: {
        jshintrc: '.jshintrc'
      },
      all: ['Gruntfile.js', '<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js', '!<%= yeoman.app %>/scripts/vendor/*'
        // 'test/spec/{,*/}*.js'
      ]
    },
    karma: {
      options: {
        files: ['test/**/*.js']
      },
      continuous: {},
      dev: {}
    },
    mocha: {
      all: {
        options: {
          run: true,
          urls: ['http://<%= connect.test.options.hostname %>:<%= connect.test.options.port %>/index.html']
        }
      }
    },
    autoprefixer: {
      options: {
        browsers: ['last 1 version']
      },
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '.tmp/styles/',
          src: '{,*/}*.css',
          dest: '.tmp/styles/'
        }]
      }
    },
    'bower-install': {
      app: {
        html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html',
        ignorePath: '<%= yeoman.app %>/'
      }
    },
    rev: {
      dist: {
        files: {
          src: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*']
        }
      }
    },
    useminPrepare: {
      options: {
        dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
      },
      html: '<%= yeoman.app %>/index.html'
    },
    usemin: {
      options: {
        dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>']
      },
      html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
      css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css']
    },
    imagemin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg}',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    svgmin: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/images',
          src: '{,*/}*.svg',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images'
        }]
      }
    },
    cssmin: {
    },
    htmlmin: {
      dist: {
        options: {
        },
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          src: '*.html',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>'
        }]
      }
    },
     copy: {
      dist: {
        files: [{
          expand: true,
          dot: true,
          cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>',
          dest: '<%= yeoman.dist %>',
          src: ['*.{ico,png,txt}', '.htaccess', 'images/{,*/}*.{webp,gif}', 'res/**', 'styles/fonts/{,*/}*.*', 'bower_components/**']
        }]
      },
      styles: {
        expand: true,
        dot: true,
        cwd: '<%= yeoman.app %>/styles',
        dest: '.tmp/styles/',
        src: '{,*/}*.css'
      }
    },
    concurrent: {
      server: [/*'copy:styles'*/ 'compass'],
      test: [/*'copy:styles'*/ 'compass'],
      dist: [/*'copy:styles'*/ 'compass', 'imagemin', 'svgmin', 'htmlmin']
    }
  });
  grunt.registerTask('server', function(target) {
    if (target === 'dist') {
      return grunt.task.run(['build', 'connect:dist:keepalive']);
    }
    grunt.task.run(['clean:server', 'concurrent:server', 'autoprefixer', 'connect:livereload', 'watch']);
  });
  grunt.registerTask('test', ['clean:server', 'concurrent:test', 'autoprefixer', 'connect:test', 'mocha']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['clean:dist', 'useminPrepare', 'concurrent:dist', 'autoprefixer', 'concat', 'cssmin', 'uglify', 'copy:dist', 'rev', 'usemin']);
  grunt.registerTask('platform-build', ['default', 'phonegap:build']);
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint',
     'build'
  ]);
};
```

Tasks are loaded with require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt) from my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "bower": "~1.3.12",
    "coffeelint": "^1.6.0",
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-concurrent": "~1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-coffee": "~0.12.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "~1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.8.0",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "~0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-handlebars": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.8.1",
    "grunt-contrib-requirejs": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-karma": "~0.9.0",
    "grunt-mocha": "~0.4.11",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-notify": "^0.3.1",
    "grunt-phonegap": "~0.15.2",
    "grunt-svgmin": "~1.0.0",
    "load-grunt-config": "^0.13.2",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.6.0",
    "time-grunt": "~1.0.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

All dependencies installed with npm install.

Comment: ...does adding the `--verbose` flag provide any additional details that points to the root of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Where are you loading your tasks? You need to load the tasks using NPM before they can be configured and executed by Grunt. See [here](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.loadnpmtasks).

Here's an example from the Grunt site:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      options: {
        banner: '/*! <%= pkg.name %> <%= grunt.template.today("yyyy-mm-dd") %> */\n'
      },
      build: {
        src: 'src/<%= pkg.name %>.js',
        dest: 'build/<%= pkg.name %>.min.js'
      }
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "uglify" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify']);

};
```

Comment: require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt) loads all tasks listed in my package.json.

Comment: @WlodzislavK. Hmmmm did you run NPM install? Are you sure the modules are there?